# Symfony Panther - How tu keep SSL on localhost?

Tags: php, selenium, symfony, ssl, localhost

I am using Panther to test my Symfony 5 application.

I need to test my Stripe payment system. I can fill out the form fields, but when I submit Stripe gives me an error:

> (index):1 You may test your Stripe.js integration over HTTP. However,
> live Stripe.js integrations must use HTTPS.

Indeed, it seems that Panther does not launch the client in HTTPS but in HTTP.

I installed the Symfony SSL certificate locally (so I can access **https://127.0.0.1:8000**)

But Panther will just run **http://127.0.0.1:9080** (9080 is the port occuped by panther when launching tests)

How could I fix this?
I did not see any option in the doc ( https://github.com/symfony/panther ), nor any way out on this subject

This is my code :

```php
$client = static::createPantherClient();
$client->request('GET', '/website/tarifs');

//fill the form and submit
```

[image]

Comment: Please share more details. How do you request the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal webserver of Panther uses http only (as you can see [in the code](https://github.com/symfony/panther/blob/main/src/PantherTestCaseTrait.php#L137)). If you want to use SSL, you have to use your own webserver that handles the encryption layer. This works as [documented](https://github.com/symfony/panther#using-an-external-web-server):

```php
    public function testMyApp(): void
    {
        $pantherClient = static::createPantherClient(['external_base_uri' => 'https://localhost']);
        // the PHP integrated web server will not be started
    }
```